# cloning an object in Javascript maintaining instanceof

Tags: javascript, clone

I want to clone an object in Javascript. I have:

```
 iPath = function () { this.heading = 0; this.path = []; };
 loop = new iPath();
```

I know with jQuery I can do something like:

```
 cloneLoop = $.extend(true, {}, loop);
```

but than

```
 assert(cloneLoop instanceof iPath, "fails because loop is not an iPath");
```

How can i do a deep clone fulfilling last assert statement?

Comment: "deep" extension means that sub-objects will be merged as well. `extend` does not clone an object, it does not preserve the prototype chain either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
cloneLoop = $.extend(true, new iPath(), loop);
```

...though I'm not sure if you'd want to do a deep copy. I'd think this would be better:

```
cloneLoop = $.extend(new iPath(), loop);
```

Answer (score 1):

If not supporting older browsers is an option, you should be able to use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
var cloneLoop = Object.create(loop);
```

Here's a demo

```
    function Foo() {
        this.x = 1;
        this.y = 1;
        this.blah = { f: "a", g: "b" };
    }

    var f = new Foo();
    var clone = Object.create(f);

    alert(clone instanceof Foo);
    alert(clone.blah.f);
```

alerts `true`, then `a` (at least on Chrome, older browsers will not support Object.create)

Comment: +1 Seems like setting it as the prototype object would be a good solution. For older browsers, you can use the typical `Object.create` patch. `function create( proto ) { function f(){} f.prototype = proto; return new f; }`

Answer (score 1):

Extend simply copies properties from one object to another.  So you have to start with a pristine copy of the object you want to copy into.  So use `new iPath()` instead of `{}`.

```
var iPath = function () { this.heading = 0; this.path = []; };
loop = new iPath();

cloneLoop = $.extend(true, new iPath(), loop);

alert(cloneLoop instanceof iPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your own `clone` method:

Something along the lines of:

```
iPath.prototype = {
  clone: function () {
    var p;
    p = new iPath();
    $.extend(true, p, this);
    return p;
  }
}
cloneLoop = loop.clone();
```